# Multer not storing file to folder and is showing null in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer

i am using nodejs with multer to create a Image file upload to my shopDB mongo DB
when i upload a image file and post the data from the form ... everything in the form gets saved in the DB but the imagename is showing null and the image is not getting stored in the file path

i am getting no error in the console while saving the form data 
and the app is running fine except for the file upload

this is how the upload is inside the form

```
<div id="img">                                
<input type='file' name="uploadpostfile">
</div>
```

THIS IS MY APP.JS

```
  const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();
    const multer = require('multer');
    const path = require("path");
    const Post = require('./models/postup');
    const uploadPath = path.join("public", Post.postImgPath);
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const imageMimeTypes = ["images/jpeg", "images/png", "images/gif"]

const upload = multer({
    dest: uploadPath,
    fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, imageMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype) )
    }
   })
const request = require("request");
const ejs = require("ejs");
require('./models/postup')
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/shopDB");
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Mongoose', {useNewUrlParser: true}, { useUnifiedTopology: true}))


const app = express();


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.post("/npost", multer(upload).single("uploadpostfile"), (req, res) => {
    let fileName = req.file != null ? req.file.filename : null
    let post = new Post({
         tag: req.body.taginput,
         title: req.body.posttitle,
         link: req.body.extlink,
         text1: req.body.textsmall,
         text2: req.body.textmedium,
         text3: req.body.textlarge,
         imgname: fileName 
    })



    post.save((err, doc) => {
        if (!err)    
            res.redirect('editor');
        else {
            console.log('Error' +err )
        }
    })

})



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
  });

app.get('/editor', (req, res) => {
    res.render('editor');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server on 3000");
})
```

Comment: your `req.file` is surely getting `undefined` value that's why it's taking only the 2nd parameter as true resulting `null` as your file address. And are you sure your `uploadPath` is right?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try after saving a post, update the image.

const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();
    const multer = require('multer');
    const path = require("path");
    const Post = require('./models/postup');
    const uploadPath = path.join("public", Post.postImgPath);
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const imageMimeTypes = ["images/jpeg", "images/png", "images/gif"]

const upload = multer({
    dest: uploadPath,
    fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, imageMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype) )
    }
   })
const request = require("request");
const ejs = require("ejs");
require('./models/postup')
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/shopDB");
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Mongoose', {useNewUrlParser: true}, { useUnifiedTopology: true}))


const app = express();


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.post("/npost", multer(upload).single("uploadpostfile"), (req, res) => {
    let fileName = req.file != null ? req.file.filename : null
    let post = new Post({
         tag: req.body.taginput,
         title: req.body.posttitle,
         link: req.body.extlink,
         text1: req.body.textsmall,
         text2: req.body.textmedium,
         text3: req.body.textlarge,

    })



    post.save((err, doc) => {
        if (!err)    
            res.redirect('editor');
        else {
            imgname = fileName;
                post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: imgname }, { 
             upsert: true, new: true }).exec((error, post) => {
            if(error) {
            res.status(500).json({ message:'internal server error' });
            } else {
            res.status(200).json({message:'image upload sucessfully.})
            console.log('Error' +err )
        }
    })

})



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
  });

app.get('/editor', (req, res) => {
    res.render('editor');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server on 3000");
})
```